# How to remove an error when launching an ASP.NET Core application in VS Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I just started learning ASP.NET Core, and as soon as I got around to adding an authentication window to the course, errors started appearing.

```
//program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Run();
```

When starting they get the following error

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.ReflectionMiddlewareBinder.CreateMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
      Hosting failed to start
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.ReflectionMiddlewareBinder.CreateMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.ReflectionMiddlewareBinder.CreateMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in c:\dotnet\aspnet\helloapp\Program.cs:line 4
```

I assume that this is due to the fact that I write the program in VS Code, since for my classmates who use VS 2022 with exactly the same code, exactly the same project file, everything works. I would like to find out the reason and try to solve it, but I can’t find anything on the Internet

Comment: you are missing builder.Services.AddAuthentication()

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0 > `builder.Services.AddAuthentication()`

Comment: You can check whether the Authentication package in the project is installed and whether it matches the project version. And check whether the authentication and Authorization middleware are added in order, and whether `services.AddAuthentication()` is used to register the service and specify the DefaultAuthenticateScheme. When registering a service, do you specify DefaultAuthenticateScheme in services.AddAuthentication()? What authentication do you need to use in your project, such as cookies or JWT? Is it MVC type or razor type about your project?